# Dynamics Nav 2009 - API order save Date error

Tags: web-services, dynamics-nav, time-format

I am using the API to save new sales orders, and everytime I send a date as one of the parameteres, it returns me the following error message:

> '2015-09-09+01:00' is not a valid date.

Any idea?

Thank you,

Bilel

Comment: Maybe because it is invalid format for Nav? Valid date would be "09.09.2015" or "09092015".

Answer (score 1):

The [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301245.aspx) data type in NAV can not contain time data. Try using the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355274.aspx) data type instead. Be sure to correct the input format.

If you are not able to change the data type inside NAV, your best bet, as stated above, is to remove the time stamp from the date entered.